# Send JSON with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Why isn't this PHP getting my links array?

```
function check_links() {

        $matches = $this->input->get('links');


        if($matches == true) {
            echo json_encode('matches is true');
        } else {
            echo json_encode('matches is false');
        } 


        //echo json_encode($matches);

    }
```

The JS

```
        var linksStr = $("#links").val();
        var matches = linksStr.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/[^\s]+/gi);

        alert(matches.length);

        for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
            alert(matches[i]);
        }

        var links = JSON.stringify(matches);

        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: links,
        url: 'publishlinks/check_links',
        success:                    
            function(response) {

                alert(response);

            }


        })
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET)` show? Or using a JS debugger, what url is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused a bit with what is trying to be achieved here.
But the JSON.stringify needs to be assigned to a value,

```
var links = JSON.stringify(matches);
```

like links

```
var links = 'links='+JSON.stringify(matches);
```

Then in your function, `$matches` should now contain your json-encoded links.
So you can use that,

```
function check_links() {
  $matches = $this->input->get('links');
  ...
  $matches = json_decode($matches); // do stuff
  ....
```